# SharePoint: Trouble Moving Files

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, folder

I wanted to restructure a SharePoint Library, creating folders and moving files inside their specific folder location.

During the process I noticed that I drag and drop the files into their respective folder, but when I want to go into that folder and get it back up to the folder structure there is no option:

[image]

I cant drag and drop the files back up and I cant use options like move-to, only delete.

Is there any reason why the files cant be moved back up and how can I fix it?

Thank you very much in advance!